# r label variable combination

Tags: r, classification, combinations

I have a dataset with three variables. Each variable can take two values "Yes" or "No". So `2^3=8` different combinations of these three variables.

```
 C1   C2   C3
 Yes  No   No
 No   Yes  No
 No   Yes  No
 No   Yes  No
 Yes  Yes  Yes 
 No   No   Yes
 No   No   No
 Yes  Yes  No
 Yes  Yes  No
 No   Yes  Yes
 Yes  No   Yes
 Yes  No   Yes
 Yes  Yes  Yes
```

How do I create a fourth column that indicates the column C1, C2, C3 combination ? The expected output would be

```
 C1   C2   C3   I
 Yes  No   No   1
 No   Yes  No   2
 No   Yes  No   2
 No   Yes  No   2
 Yes  Yes  Yes  8
 No   No   Yes  3 
 No   No   No   4 
 Yes  Yes  No   5
 Yes  Yes  No   5
 No   Yes  Yes  6
 Yes  No   Yes  7 
 Yes  No   Yes  7
 Yes  Yes  Yes  8
```

Comment: Is there an order of importance for labelling

Comment: @akrun, no. Just identifying the group the combination of C1,C2,C3 values belong.

Comment: if it can be any order, then `with(df1, as.integer(interaction(C1, C2, C3, lex.order = TRUE)))` or `library(dplyr);df1 %>% mutate(I = group_indices(., C1, C2, C3))` or `v1 <- do.call(paste, df1); match(v1, unique(v1))`

Comment: You have obviously assigned a value to each combination, and I think you should provide a list of references how you are mapping each combination to the value.

If you are flexible in the mapping, I might suggest an elegant solution may lie in converting your Yes / No to 1 / 0, each column then being a 2^0 for C1, 2^1 for C2 and 2^2 for C3, and then summing that up, a simple mathematical solution.

Comment: @Nadia, If I convert values to 1s and 0s and do a row sum, then I will get 2 for X1=1, X2=0, X3=1. and X1=1, X2=1, X3=0. These two are not the same.

Comment: @Nadia, you should post that as a solution. I worked up the exact same solution and was about to post it. Then I read your comment. The solution by chinsoon is nice, but the approach you propose provides extra nuggets.

Comment: @JosephWood thanks for the chance to post, unfortunately, I am actually quite swamped atm, so please go ahead, since you have already worked up the solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option using `data.table`:

```
DT[order(C1, C2, C3), Idx := rleidv(.SD)]
```

Or using a lookup join as mentioned by Nadia so that you can control the indexing:

```
x <- c("No", "Yes")
DT[CJ(C1=x, C2=x, C3=x)[, Idx := .I], on=.NATURAL, Idx := Idx]
```

output:

```
     C1  C2  C3 Idx
 1: Yes  No  No   5
 2:  No Yes  No   3
 3:  No Yes  No   3
 4:  No Yes  No   3
 5: Yes Yes Yes   8
 6:  No  No Yes   2
 7:  No  No  No   1
 8: Yes Yes  No   7
 9: Yes Yes  No   7
10:  No Yes Yes   4
11: Yes  No Yes   6
12: Yes  No Yes   6
13: Yes Yes Yes   8
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("C1   C2   C3
Yes  No   No
No   Yes  No
No   Yes  No
No   Yes  No
Yes  Yes  Yes 
No   No   Yes
No   No   No
Yes  Yes  No
Yes  Yes  No
No   Yes  Yes
Yes  No   Yes
Yes  No   Yes
Yes  Yes  Yes")
```

Comment: Won't this restart the numbering if it isn't sorted first?

Comment: @thelatemail, thanks. we can add `order` in `i` if required.

Comment: @chinsoon12, how is row 5 and 13 different, they both have same values ? I was expecting them to be same.

Comment: @RiloDinga posted too quickly. have updated output after addressing thelatemail's comment

Answer (score 3):

As @Nadia points out in the comments, there is a natural method for obtaining the order using powers of 2. If we had other options in addition to "Yes" and "No" (e.g. "Maybe") we would use powers of 3 (or 4, 5, etc.). In base `R` we have:

```
df$Index <- apply(df, 1, function(x) sum(2^(which(x == "Yes") - 1L)) + 1L)
```

This gives:

```
df
    C1  C2  C3 Index
1  Yes  No  No     2
2   No Yes  No     3
3   No Yes  No     3
4   No Yes  No     3
5  Yes Yes Yes     8
6   No  No Yes     5
7   No  No  No     1
8  Yes Yes  No     4
9  Yes Yes  No     4
10  No Yes Yes     7
11 Yes  No Yes     6
12 Yes  No Yes     6
13 Yes Yes Yes     8
```

I doubt this is faster than the `data.table` version, however the intent of the answer is purely pedagogical.

Here is the input for reference:

```
df <- read.table(text = "C1   C2   C3
                        Yes  No   No
                        No   Yes  No
                        No   Yes  No
                        No   Yes  No
                        Yes  Yes  Yes 
                        No   No   Yes
                        No   No   No
                        Yes  Yes  No
                        Yes  Yes  No
                        No   Yes  Yes
                        Yes  No   Yes
                        Yes  No   Yes
                        Yes  Yes  Yes",
                header = TRUE)
```

Comment: that makes sense. Thanks I will try that.